# CMake is throwing an error while Installing OpenCV

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake

I am using [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-macos/) document as a guide
and i ran through this error

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RELEASE"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /installation/OpenCV-/share/licenses/opencv4.
  Maybe need administrative privileges.
```

Comment: Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225288/install-cmake-occurs-a-error-how-to-deal-with-it) answer of your question?

Comment: Yes it does thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem as you. I found out that it is not a permission problem, but a path problem of OpenCV installation.

I use the following method for successfully installing OpenCV4.2.0 to my computer.

Change the path:

`-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = $cwd/installation/OpenCV-4.2.0`

To

`-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = /usr/local`

[image]

[image]